# How to export/import es6 js library

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I am creating a Es6 JS library with common tasks I usually use in my frontends and I have a few questions about how to organize so I can export/import the way I want. I have it organized this way:

```
src/
  module/
    function.js
    index.js // Module, exports grouped functions
  index.js // Enty point, exports entire library
```

src/index.js:

```
import module from './module/index';

const library = {
  module
};

export default library;
```

src/module/index.js:

```
import func from './function';

const module = {
  func
};

export default module;
```

src/module/function.js:

```
function func() {
  console.log('do things');
};

export default func;
```

I have no problems accesing those methods inside the library but I don't know how to configure webpack to be able to access them from outside the way I want. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
// Use all methods 
import Library from 'library';

Library.module.func();

// Use only methods from module
import module from 'library/module';

module.func();

// Use only 1 function
import func from 'library/module/func';

func();
```

By the way, how do I access the library If I just add the the JS created by webpack when I build the library. I mean, will I be able to do this?

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<script>
    Library.module.func();
</script>
```

I have tried to configure webpack on my own with no luck. Library is always {}, undefined or I have to use Library.default. Some other times is not global. I have tried it with Vue and this is the result:

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<script>
    const a = Library.default;

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {},
      methods: {
        buttonClick() {
          a.module.func(); // works
          Library.default.module.func(); // CRASH cause is undefined
        }
      },
      created() {
        Library.default.module.func(); // works ???
      }
    });
</script>
```

To sum up:

1. I don't know how to properly configure webpack to be able to import library, module or single functions.
2. I don't even know If the way I organized the library is correct.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no problems accesing those methods inside the library but I
>   don't know how to configure webpack to be able to access them from
>   outside the way I want

You need to use `resolve.alias`, which would allow you from any code processed by your webpack config to use your library the way you want, for example:

```
alias: { 
  library: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
}
```

Then you can do,

```
import Library from 'library';
import Library from 'library/module/function';
```

etc.

> By the way, how do I access the library If I just add the the JS
>   created by webpack when I build the library. I mean, will I be able to
>   do this?

You should be able to do this configuring your webpack output correctly to expose your library in the `window`. Have a look at the `output` fields `library` and `libraryTarget`. 
Basically you can tell webpack to export your library in the root scope (window):

```
output: {
   ...
   library: 'library',
   libraryTarget: 'var'
   ...
}
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
<script src="library.js"></script>
<script> library.module.func() <script>
```

The important part here is you will be exposing in the `window` whatever your webpack `entry point` is exporting.